# CORS - Java and Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jax-rs

I'm getting the typical Cors error in the UI. For test reasons, I want to disable it completely. What I find strange is that I get 200 and I can see the "Hello World" in the response in Chrome debug but I get:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://localhost:8101/app/services/rest/user' from origin
>   'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I have this bean

```
 <jaxrs:server id="processServices" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
       <ref bean="userServiceBean"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
 </jaxrs:server>

 <bean id="userServiceBean" class="com.package.services.UserService"/>
```

And a basic service:

```
@Service("processUserService")
public class UserService {

    @GET
    @Path("/user")
    public String getUser() {
        return "Hello World"
    }
}
```

I saw on the stackoverflow and they told to use

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

   @Override
   public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
                      final ContainerResponseContext cres) throws IOException {
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
   }
}
```

But still the same error. I debugged and this method is not being called.

What am I missing here??

Comment: Did you register your `CORSFilter`?

Comment: @Dancrumb. No I just did what I said. What to you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register this provider with your server.

Something like:

```
<jaxrs:server id="processServices" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
       <ref bean="userServiceBean"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean="corsfilterProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
 </jaxrs:server>

 <bean id="corsfilterProvider" class="your.filters.full.name"/>
 <bean id="userServiceBean" class="com.package.services.UserService"/>
```

Comment: Amazing. Thx ;)))